# Adding headers into CSV output file using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2012, header, console.writeline

I am trying to add headers into the CSV file and as a headers I would like to have the variables names used in the `WriteLine`.

Here you have my code:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))                    
{
    for (int s = 0; s < pr.Length; ++s)
    {
        string[] UsersIDS = new string[] {""};
        UsersIDS = db.GetUsersList(pr[s].ProjectID);
        file.WriteLine(
             pr[s].ProjectID + '"' + ',' + 
             '"' +  pr[s].ProjectTitle + '"' + ',' + 
             pr[s].PublishStatus + '"' + ',' + 
             UsersIDS.Length); 
    }
}
```

Comment: header for the CSV is on the first line. so just do a writeline just after creating the File. Header1,Header2,.. and then start writing data for every line representing each row

Comment: So this code is printing out each line in the CSV? You want the header first? Just call file.Writeline before the for loop with whatever you want in header?

Comment: What is purpose of variable pr?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy the variable pr its an array from the web service call that has been initialized before. the csv file is correct but it does not include headers, so I am trying to include them, thanks

Comment: Hi @AndyWiesendanger yes the file gets the output requested but I am stuck including for each column a header

Comment: What is pr? you example question is confusing when you leave out items which pertain to that one block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose you following modification

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))                    
{
    file.WriteLine("ProjectID, ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,Length");
    for (int s = 0; s < pr.Length; ++s)
    {
        string[] UsersIDS = new string[] {""};
        UsersIDS = db.GetUsersList(pr[s].ProjectID);
        file.WriteLine( pr[s].ProjectID + '"' + ',' + '"' + pr[s].ProjectTitle + '"' + ',' + pr[s].PublishStatus + '"' + ',' + UsersIDS.Length); 

}//end of for
```

Answer (score 2):

Just regular `WriteLine` with constant string seem to be what you are after (unless you want to get names of columns via reflection or some other way):

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))                    
{
    file.WriteLine( "ProjectID,ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,UsersIDS_Length"); 

    for (int index = 0; index < pr.Length; index++)
    {
        var usersIds = db.GetUsersList(pr[s].ProjectID);
        file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3}",
           pr[s].ProjectID, pr[s].ProjectTitle,
           pr[s].PublishStatus, usersIds.Length); 
    }
}
```

(Sound like you also wanted quotes around title... the rest of quotes looked unbalanced).

Comment: Hi, I just tested the suggested modification and its very neat! Sorry I haven't tested correctly before. I really like this one! thanks