# Writing csv file from C#

Tags: c#, file, csv, text

I have my insertion into text file code as:

```
foreach (var kvauthor in _tauthorData)
{
   foreach (var coAuthor in kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors)
   {
      twObjClus.WriteLine("AuthorID: {0}, AuthorName: {1}, ClusterID: {2}, PaperID: {3},  
                           CoAuthors: {4}, PaperCategory: {5}, Venue: {6}, Year: {4}",  
                           eAuthor.AuthorID, eAuthor.AuthorName, curCluster.GetClusterID(),  
                           kvauthor.Key, coAuthor, kvauthor.Value.PaperCategory,  
                           kvauthor.Value.VenueID, kvauthor.Value.Year);

   }
}
```

I want to insert all these data into a csv file whereas I've tried this as:

```
var csv = new StringBuilder();  

foreach (var kvauthor in _tauthorData)
{
   foreach (var coAuthor in kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors)
   {
      csv.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",AuthorID: {0}, AuthorName: {1}, ClusterID: {2}, PaperID: {3},  
                           CoAuthors: {4}, PaperCategory: {5}, Venue: {6}, Year: {4}",  
                           eAuthor.AuthorID, eAuthor.AuthorName, curCluster.GetClusterID(),  
                           kvauthor.Key, coAuthor, kvauthor.Value.PaperCategory,  
                           kvauthor.Value.VenueID, kvauthor.Value.Year);

   }
}
```

How can I insert this data row by row into csv file with column headers?

Comment: This is not the case, my data to be written is from variables in the code

Comment: Whereas I need to have Column headers at the top and values in csv format

Comment: Try to tell what you **can't** do. [Append line to file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2837020/1997232)? Or maybe you don't know what is [csv-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) ? Maybe the problem is [how to insert column headers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32357209/1997232)?

Comment: I'm unable to show column headers once at the top of csv

Comment: That's [easy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32357209/1997232). You have to create file (or `StringBuilder`) and add column headers line once outside (before) cycle. Then in the cycle you just add data into corresponding columns (typically using indexes).

Comment: and me getting my data all in a single row instead different rows by using code which I've shown above

Answer (score -1):

Adding column headers is trivial, just do it **once** (when opening file or creating instance of e.g. `StringBuilder` which will be used to add rows later).

```
var csv = new StringBuilder();  

// add column headers first
csv.AppendLine("AuthorID,AuthorName, ..."); // and so on

// add data
foreach (var kvauthor in _tauthorData)
    foreach (var coAuthor in kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors)
    {
        csv.AppendLine($"{coAuthor.AuthorId},{coAuthor.Name}, ..."); // and so on
        // if you don't have C# 6.0
        // csv.AppendFormat("{0},{1}, ... {N}", coAuthor.AuthorId, coAuthor.Name, ..., Environmental.NewLine");
    }

File.WriteAllText(path, csv.ToString());
```

Note: you can use [`AppendLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257(v=vs.110).aspx) to add [`Environmental.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) automatically, otherwise (if using `AppendFormat`) add it to the end of `string` manually.

Comment: There is some error i.e. `)` expected

Comment: I've used it as `csv.AppendLine($"{eAuthor.AuthorID},{eAuthor.AuthorName},{curCluster.GetClusterID()},{kvauthor.Key},{coAuthor},{kvauthor.Value.PaperCategory},{kvauthor.Value.VenueID},{kvauthor.Value.Year}");` but getting error i.e. `)` expected

Comment: Also the `$` sign unexpected

Comment: If you seek debug help, then post your code and exact error message (as a new question of course). I am not able to help with information given in that comment line. If you don't have [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) (require C# 6.0), then you have to use `string.Format()` or keep as you do now `AppendLine`, but simply add `Environmental.NewLine` at the end (as per note in the answer).

Comment: See edit. C# 7.0 is *soon*...